# Device to balance water pressure

Tags: hydraulics

I have a situation where I have two water supply lines and both need to be the same pressure. One of the lines is normally always a little higher than the other, but by different amounts depending on circumstances.

Is there a special kind of valve that will automatically restrict the high line so that it always matches the pressure of the low line?

Comment: what have you researched and found so far?